# Is it possible to make a 2 sided button using QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to make a 2 sided button, something like the picture below. When the user hovers the two colors should switch side (left becomes red, right becomes blue).

So far my thoughts are that I could add 2 labels inside a Q PushButton, but that doesn't seem to be working as the button doesn't size properly and hover effects don't seem to work.

Note that right is intended to be smaller from the left side.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsCj8.png]

Instead I get this....

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl4xd.png]

Here's my current code.

**custombutton.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMBUTTON_H
#define CUSTOMBUTTON_H

#include <QWidget>

class CustomButton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // CUSTOMBUTTON_H
```

**custombutton.cpp**

```
#include "custombutton.h"

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

CustomButton::CustomButton(
        QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    button->setGeometry(10, 20, geometry().width(), geometry().height());
    button->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

    QLabel* left = new QLabel("Left", button);
    QLabel* right = new QLabel("Right", button);

    left->setStyleSheet("QLabel { "
                        "background-color:blue;"
                        "padding: 30px;"
                        "}"
                        "QButton:hover QLabel {"
                        "background-color:red;"
                        "}");
    right->setStyleSheet("QLabel { "
                         "background-color:red;"
                         "padding: 10px;"
                         "}"
                         "QButton:hover QLabel {"
                         "background-color:blue;"
                         "}");

    button->adjustSize();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "custombutton.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    CustomButton* custom = new CustomButton(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you have to restructure the CustomButton class, I do not understand why it inherits from QWidget, being able to inherit from QPushButton directly.

On the other hand, for both `QLabel`s to occupy equidistant parts, a `QHBoxLayout` must be used.

`QLabels` must have an Alignment `Qt::AlignCenter`.

The qss can not do conditionals of many levels, only handle the pseudo-states, for example in the following code:

```
"QButton:hover QLabel {"
    "background-color:blue;"
"}"
```

the `QLabel` will not change when you enter the mouse to the button even if the `QButton` is corrected to `QPushButton`.

To handle the change I will use the events `enterEvent` and `leaveEvent`.

If you want the right item to have the same width you should always use `setFixedWidth()`.

Code:

**custombutton.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMBUTTON_H
#define CUSTOMBUTTON_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

class CustomButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *event);
private:
    QLabel left;
    QLabel right;
    const QString leftqss = "QLabel { "
                            "background-color:blue;"
                            "}";
    const QString rightqss = "QLabel { "
                             "background-color:red;"
                             "}";
};


#endif // CUSTOMBUTTON_H
```

**custombutton.cpp**

```
#include "custombutton.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>

CustomButton::CustomButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    move(10, 20);
    setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    right.setFixedWidth(50);

    left.setText("Left");
    right.setText("Right");
    left.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    right.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    hlay->addWidget(&left);
    hlay->addWidget(&right);
    hlay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    hlay->setSpacing(0);

    left.setStyleSheet(leftqss);
    right.setStyleSheet(rightqss);

    left.adjustSize();
    right.adjustSize();
}

void CustomButton::enterEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    left.setStyleSheet(rightqss);
    right.setStyleSheet(leftqss);
    QPushButton::enterEvent(event);
}

void CustomButton::leaveEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    left.setStyleSheet(leftqss);
    right.setStyleSheet(rightqss);
    QPushButton::leaveEvent(event);
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...
CustomButton* custom = new CustomButton(this);
// Stable a new width to visualize that the right item always has the same width
custom->resize(200, custom->height()); 
...
```

[image]

You can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/50570554).

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to use layouts because they force the labels to be the same size.... I want the right side to be about 50px in width ALWAYS, and the left side to take up however much space is required by the left Label text & padding. Is that possible?

Comment: @Rick 
Yes it is possible, wait a moment

Comment: Yes this works, but I did not want to have to specify the size of the button. I wanted the left side to automatically scale to fit the text inside of it (with 20-30px of padding too). Thanks as always.